# What I am Attempting is if i click a radio button a number would be inserted into a text box. When button is clicked it prints to root

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have researched for 3 weeks and could find no solution.
I have read numerous tags and have also tried modifying code
Most of the tags refer to Java or some other programming language other than Python
My file has upwards of 80 frame which will all have 3 buttons and 1 textbox.
I sent over 1 frame with 3 radio buttons and a textbox.
Would this work or should I go in a different direction.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("1000x900")



def func1(event):
    insert("")
    textbox1.insert('1.5')
def onclick1():
    textbox1.insert('<Return>', func1)



button_var1 = tk.IntVar()


frame1 = Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")

label = Label(frame2, text="Select # Of Units", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady= 1, padx=3, sticky= "W")

textbox1 = Text(frame2, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=2)
textbox1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")

button1=Radiobutton(frame2, text="1 Unit ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here

Comment: You should use only one `IntVar` for the three radiobuttons and assign different `value` options to them.  Also use same function for the `command` option as well.  Then you can use `textbox1.insert()` to insert the required value into the text box inside that callback function.

Comment: Each textbox will be associated with a different piece of equipment. Eventually i hope to have a final textbox that will equal all proceeding boxes.  I tried a few different changes and i get an exception error.          If I could see a piece of code I am certain I could move forward.

Comment: What do you want on the line *"textbox1.insert('<Return>', func1)"* actually? You want to insert something into the textbox or bind `Return` key to a function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert something into the text box whenever the radio button is click, just modify your code as below:

```py
def onclick1():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end') # clear the text box
    textbox1.insert('end', '1.5') # insert whatever you want into text box

...

button1 = Radiobutton(frame2, text="1 Unit", variable=button_var1, command=onclick1)
...
```